# May women read the haftarah

Tags: halacha, women, tractate-megillah, haftarah, orach-chaim

The accepted orthodox Halacha is that women do not read from the weekly Torah portion publicly, and this is found in [tractate Megillah 23a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.23a.11). My question is, would it be permissible for a woman to read the haftarah, or is that problematic for the same reason?

Comment: "Reading haftarah" traditionally meant getting the aliyah of maftir. Assuming the latter is included in the Gemara's line about how women shouldn't, then the former would be as well.

Comment: It should depend on the reason of kavod ha tzibbur. If it’s a tzniyus issue then there should be no difference what she’s reading. If it’s an insult because it seems that there are no men who know how to read, then perhaps just like we allow a katan we can allow a woman

Comment: Originally the Haftara reader would also lead the Musaf service. The Mishna (Megillah 4:5) explains what to do if the reader can't lead Musaf since he's a minor, but doesn't explain what to do if the reason is gender.

Comment: @DoubleAA and even if we read that Mishna as saying to give Mussaf to someone who *routinely* reads Haftarah (vs. every time), your point still holds.